# why MRL in vlcj are not working

Tags: java, vlcj

i am trying to Specify a single MRL in vlcj i post a question but the answer was not right completely 
this code i toke from github for vlcj i changed the MRL but it is not working the error message at the end

```
    /*
 * This file is part of VLCJ.
 *
 * VLCJ is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * VLCJ is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with VLCJ.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 *
 * Copyright 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014 Caprica Software Limited.
 */

package uk.co.caprica.vlcj.test.aspect;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerFactory;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.videosurface.CanvasVideoSurface;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.test.VlcjTest;

/**
 * A test for video aspect ratio.
 * <p>
 * The red colouring on the video canvas shows the unused portion of the video surface - the client
 * application can resize the video canvas to reclaim this unused area without affecting the video
 * size/aspect (ordinarily resizing would stretch or compress the video).
 * <p>
 * Any black area shown on the top/left/bottom/right of the video are the black bars present in the
 * source material.
 * <p>
 * The panel with the white background is simply to provide context.
 */
public class AspectTest extends VlcjTest {

    /**
     * The standard aspect ratios.
     */
    private static final String[][] ASPECTS = {
        {"<choose...>",     null },
        {      "16:10",  "16:10" },
        {      "16:9" ,  "16:9"  },
        {    "1.85:1" , "185:100"},
        {    "2.21:1" , "221:100"},
        {    "2.35:1" , "235:100"},
        {    "2.39:1" , "239:100"},
        {       "5:3" ,   "5:3"  },
        {       "4:3" ,   "4:3"  },
        {       "5:4" ,   "5:4"  },
        {       "1:1" ,   "1:1"  }
    };

    private static final String HELP_TEXT =
        "<html>Select a standard apsect ratio from the list box, or enter a custom aspect ratio and press enter/return.<br/><br/>" +
        "For the custom aspect ratio, use:<ul>" +
        "<li>W:H, e.g. 16:9 and the values must be integers</li>" +
        "</ul></html>";

    private MediaPlayerFactory factory;
    private EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private CanvasVideoSurface videoSurface;

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JPanel videoPane;
    private Canvas videoCanvas;
    private JPanel controlsPane;
    private JLabel standardAspectLabel;
    private JComboBox standardAspectComboBox;
    private JLabel customAspectLabel;
    private JTextField customAspectTextField;
    private JButton pauseButton;
    private JLabel helpText;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if(args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("Specify a single MRL");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        setLookAndFeel();

        final String mrl = args[0];

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new AspectTest().start(file:\\\\C:\\Users\\isslam\\Downloads\\gg.mp4);
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public AspectTest() {
        factory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
        mediaPlayer = factory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();

        videoPane = new JPanel();
        videoPane.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 2), new EmptyBorder(16, 16, 16, 16)));
        videoPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        videoPane.setBackground(Color.white);

        videoCanvas = new Canvas();
        videoCanvas.setBackground(Color.red);
        videoCanvas.setSize(720, 350);

        videoPane.add(videoCanvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        videoSurface = factory.newVideoSurface(videoCanvas);

        mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(videoSurface);

        standardAspectLabel = new JLabel("Standard Aspect:");
        standardAspectLabel.setDisplayedMnemonic('s');

        standardAspectComboBox = new JComboBox(ASPECTS);
        standardAspectComboBox.setEditable(false);
        standardAspectComboBox.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                JLabel l = (JLabel)super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
                String[] val = (String[])value;
                l.setText(val[0]);
                return l;
            }
        });

        standardAspectLabel.setLabelFor(standardAspectComboBox);

        customAspectLabel = new JLabel("Custom Aspect:");
        customAspectLabel.setDisplayedMnemonic('c');

        customAspectTextField = new JTextField(10);
        customAspectTextField.setFocusAccelerator('c');

        pauseButton = new JButton("Pause");
        pauseButton.setMnemonic('p');

        controlsPane = new JPanel();
        controlsPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(controlsPane, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        controlsPane.add(standardAspectLabel);
        controlsPane.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(4));
        controlsPane.add(standardAspectComboBox);
        controlsPane.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(12));
        controlsPane.add(customAspectLabel);
        controlsPane.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(4));
        controlsPane.add(customAspectTextField);
        controlsPane.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(4));
        controlsPane.add(pauseButton);

        helpText = new JLabel(HELP_TEXT);

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(16, 16, 16, 16));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(16, 16));
        contentPane.add(helpText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        contentPane.add(videoPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(controlsPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame = new JFrame("vlcj aspect ratio test");
        frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/vlcj-logo.png")).getImage());
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();

        standardAspectComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Object selectedItem = standardAspectComboBox.getSelectedItem();
                if(selectedItem != null) {
                    String[] value = (String[])selectedItem;
                    mediaPlayer.setAspectRatio(value[1]);
                }
            }
        });

        customAspectTextField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String value = customAspectTextField.getText();
                mediaPlayer.setAspectRatio(value);
            }
        });

        pauseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }
        });
    }

    private void start(String mrl) {
        frame.setVisible(true);

        mediaPlayer.playMedia(mrl);
    }
}
```

the error message

```
C:\Users\isslam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\aspicts-vlcj\src\uk\co\caprica\vlcj\test\aspect\AspectTest.java:116: error: ')' expected
                new AspectTest().start(file:\\\\C:\\Users\\isslam\\Downloads\\gg.mp4);
C:\Users\isslam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\aspicts-vlcj\src\uk\co\caprica\vlcj\test\aspect\AspectTest.java:116: error: illegal character: \92
                new AspectTest().start(file:\\\\C:\\Users\\isslam\\Downloads\\gg.mp4);
C:\Users\isslam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\aspicts-vlcj\src\uk\co\caprica\vlcj\test\aspect\AspectTest.java:116: error: illegal character: \92
                new AspectTest().start(file:\\\\C:\\Users\\isslam\\Downloads\\gg.mp4);
C:\Users\isslam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\aspicts-vlcj\src\uk\co\caprica\vlcj\test\aspect\AspectTest.java:116: error: illegal character: \92
                new AspectTest().start(file:\\\\C:\\Users\\isslam\\Downloads\\gg.mp4);
C:\Users\isslam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\aspicts-vlcj\src\uk\co\caprica\vlcj\test\aspect\AspectTest.java:116: error: illegal character: \92
                new AspectTest().start(file:\\\\C:\\Users\\isslam\\Downloads\\gg.mp4);
C:\Users\isslam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\aspicts-vlcj\src\uk\co\caprica\vlcj\test\aspect\AspectTest.java:116: error: illegal character: \92
                new AspectTest().start(file:\\\\C:\\Users\\isslam\\Downloads\\gg.mp4);
C:\Users\isslam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\aspicts-vlcj\src\uk\co\caprica\vlcj\test\aspect\AspectTest.java:116: error: illegal character: \92
                new AspectTest().start(file:\\\\C:\\Users\\isslam\\Downloads\\gg.mp4);
C:\Users\isslam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\aspicts-vlcj\src\uk\co\caprica\vlcj\test\aspect\AspectTest.java:116: error: illegal character: \92
                new AspectTest().start(file:\\\\C:\\Users\\isslam\\Downloads\\gg.mp4);
C:\Users\isslam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\aspicts-vlcj\src\uk\co\caprica\vlcj\test\aspect\AspectTest.java:116: error: illegal character: \92
                new AspectTest().start(file:\\\\C:\\Users\\isslam\\Downloads\\gg.mp4);
C:\Users\isslam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\aspicts-vlcj\src\uk\co\caprica\vlcj\test\aspect\AspectTest.java:116: error: illegal character: \92
                new AspectTest().start(file:\\\\C:\\Users\\isslam\\Downloads\\gg.mp4);
C:\Users\isslam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\aspicts-vlcj\src\uk\co\caprica\vlcj\test\aspect\AspectTest.java:116: error: not a statement
                new AspectTest().start(file:\\\\C:\\Users\\isslam\\Downloads\\gg.mp4);
C:\Users\isslam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\aspicts-vlcj\src\uk\co\caprica\vlcj\test\aspect\AspectTest.java:116: error: illegal character: \92
                new AspectTest().start(file:\\\\C:\\Users\\isslam\\Downloads\\gg.mp4);
C:\Users\isslam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\aspicts-vlcj\src\uk\co\caprica\vlcj\test\aspect\AspectTest.java:116: error: illegal character: \92
                new AspectTest().start(file:\\\\C:\\Users\\isslam\\Downloads\\gg.mp4);
C:\Users\isslam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\aspicts-vlcj\src\uk\co\caprica\vlcj\test\aspect\AspectTest.java:116: error: not a statement
                new AspectTest().start(file:\\\\C:\\Users\\isslam\\Downloads\\gg.mp4);
C:\Users\isslam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\aspicts-vlcj\src\uk\co\caprica\vlcj\test\aspect\AspectTest.java:116: error: illegal character: \92
                new AspectTest().start(file:\\\\C:\\Users\\isslam\\Downloads\\gg.mp4);
C:\Users\isslam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\aspicts-vlcj\src\uk\co\caprica\vlcj\test\aspect\AspectTest.java:116: error: not a statement
                new AspectTest().start(file:\\\\C:\\Users\\isslam\\Downloads\\gg.mp4);
C:\Users\isslam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\aspicts-vlcj\src\uk\co\caprica\vlcj\test\aspect\AspectTest.java:116: error: ';' expected
                new AspectTest().start(file:\\\\C:\\Users\\isslam\\Downloads\\gg.mp4);
17 errors
C:\Users\isslam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\aspicts-vlcj\nbproject\build-impl.xml:920: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\isslam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\aspicts-vlcj\nbproject\build-impl.xml:260: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: plz if you like to answer my question walk with me to the end don't just say this is simple this can be google walk with me tell it work plz plz plz

Answer (score 0):

Really?

```
new AspectTest().start(file:\\\\C:\\Users\\isslam\\Downloads\\gg.mp4);
```

Should be this:

```
new AspectTest().start("file:\\\\C:\\Users\\isslam\\Downloads\\gg.mp4");
```

Comment: no there is no error but again the same message Specify a single MRL

Comment: I answered the question asked. Your comment on my answer is another question with a different answer. You have to look at the code that causes the error you complain about: "if(args.length != 1)..." - you have to pass the MRL in as a *command-line argument*. This is a Java fundamental, and you are going to find using vlcj *very* hard if you do not have a strong grasp of Java fundamentals.

Comment: So caprica, is the MRL correct? What is the correct MRL to be used for Windows files? For instance, for a file `D:\sample.mp4`.

Comment: @SelcukBozdag that is a different question that should not be answered in a comment here